# Is it possible to lock down the http / https proxy settings on a Windows Phone?

Tags: tls, proxy, http-proxy, windows-phone, squid

Is there any way to lock down the [proxy settings](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-add-proxy-server-wireless-connection-windows-phone-8) on a Windows Phone so that they can't be changed by anyone but the person with the password?

Answer (score 4):

To achieve that, you need to choose/use a Mobile Device Management (MDM) solution.

There are some solutions about MDM for Windows Phone / Windows 10 Mobile. Look:

- From Microsoft:
  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn771709.aspx
  https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/windows/whats-new/device-management
- Solutions from other companies: just do a web search for:
  mdm "windows phone"